# Max-heap Ordering

Tags: arrays, binary-tree, heapsort

If **A [1 .. n]** is a max-heap, where may be the second, the third , the fourth... largest elements of the array?

> [1]
>
> [2] [3]
>
> [4] [5] [6] [7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, the first element is the maximum. Following it are its children at positions 2*k and 2*k+1. So if you are 1 based, the next numbers in size are at 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do it like this - The largest element is at the root. Who are the candidates for 2nd largest and 3rd largest ? Ans -> The immediate children of root. Why? Because all elements below the children of root will be lesser than the children of root.

Similarly who are candidate for fourth largest ? The children of 2nd and 3rd largest element i.e. Nodes from index 4 to index 7.